# Android: sending back an intent to fragment losing data

Tags: android, fragment

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Well I want send the user to google maps and select a location from fragment. But after saving the location the user gets back to the fragment but the saved data is missing.

The Fragment has code like this:

```
mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SlamMap.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 9998);
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.slide_out_left);
        }
    });
```

and the fragment receives the result intent like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case (9998): {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i("RUN", data.toString());
            String lon = data.getStringExtra("LON");
            String lat = data.getStringExtra("LAT");
            setLocation(lon, lat);
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Well ok and the code in the MapActivity processes the data like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.addLoc:
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        if (itemizedOverlay.getLat() != 0 && itemizedOverlay.getLon() != 0) {
            Log.i("RUN", "" + (long) (itemizedOverlay.getLon()));
            resultIntent.putExtra("LON",
                    String.valueOf((long) itemizedOverlay.getLon()));
            resultIntent.putExtra("LAT",
                    String.valueOf((long) itemizedOverlay.getLat()));
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right,
                    R.anim.slide_in_right);
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
}
```

But as I said the onActivityResult is called by the setResult but the Intent has no information about my two Strings LON and LAT.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
String lon = data.getStringExtra("LON");
String lat = data.getStringExtra("LAT");
```

by

```
String lon = data.getExtras().getString("LON");
String lat = data.getExtras().getString("LAT");
```

Regards

Comment: Nope that's not it. I've debugged the Intent, and there are no extras in it. So in somehow the intent loses the information during sending it back to the Fragment.

Comment: Did you check if LAT and LON are set on onMenuItemSelected method ?

Comment: yes they are `Log.i("RUN", "" + (long) (itemizedOverlay.getLon()));` tells me a number